# Why "echo f" in the case of clearing conntrack table doesn't work on debian?

Tags: debian, networking, iptables, firewall

Many people don't clear the conntrack table when they want to reload their firewall rules. When you have some ESTABLISHED connections, all the sessions won't be affected when you add a rule that blocks some of the connections in question (in the NEW state). The only way to make sure that this isn't going to happen is to kill all the sessions by clearing the conntrack table. In this case all packets will hit the INVALID rule and you have to make a new connection, which now goes through the new rules of `iptables`.

In OpenWRT, you can simply do the following:

```
# echo f > /proc/net/nf_conntrack
```

But unfortunately this solution doesn't work on debian.

```
# echo f > /proc/net/nf_conntrack
echo: write error: Input/output error
```

Here's why:

```
# ls -al /proc/net/nf_conntrack
-r--r----- 1 root root 0 2016-06-05 10:45:52 /proc/net/nf_conntrack
```

On debian you have to install the `conntrack` package, and type the following command:

```
# conntrack -F
conntrack v1.4.3 (conntrack-tools): connection tracking table has been emptied.
```

Why `echo f` doesn't work on debian? Is there a way to make it work somehow, or am I forced to use the `conntrack` tool?

Comment: Same thing here, although I could swear the difference is not about it being specific to OpenWRT, but more due to the functionality not being supported in newer kernels, and/or files having different names in proc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenWRT maintains several specific kernel patches. Amont them, there is the specific patch providing the feature you complain is lacking in Debian. It is actually available *only* in OpenWRT.

Choosing a git history near the asked question's timeline, for kernel 4.4.

[`600-netfilter_conntrack_flush.patch`](https://git.openwrt.org/?p=openwrt/openwrt.git;a=blob;f=target/linux/generic/patches-4.4/600-netfilter_conntrack_flush.patch;h=879473965871ecb306934c037583eb385efaad10;hb=621677154f39f2e0b698a558b8b795db84a8e014):

> ```
> static const struct file_operations ct_file_ops = {
>        .owner   = THIS_MODULE,
>        .open    = ct_open,       .read    = seq_read,
>  +     .write   = ct_file_write,
>        .llseek  = seq_lseek,
>        .release = seq_release_net,
>  };
> @@ -393,7 +450,7 @@ static int nf_conntrack_standalone_init_
>  {
>         struct proc_dir_entry *pde;
>
> -       pde = proc_create("nf_conntrack", 0440, net->proc_net, &ct_file_ops);
> +       pde = proc_create("nf_conntrack", 0660, net->proc_net, &ct_file_ops);
>         if (!pde)
>                 goto out_nf_conntrack;
> ```

While I couldn't figure out where the specific `f` syntax is handled (outside of the snippet above), the snipped above clearly shows OpenWRT adds a patch to allow writing to  `/proc/net/nf_conntrack` which is read-only on normal kernels.

It's still [available today for kernel 5.4](https://git.openwrt.org/?p=openwrt/openwrt.git;a=blob;f=target/linux/generic/pending-5.4/600-netfilter_conntrack_flush.patch;h=14d3a37a8ccb2d0a1512c488abf7ae7bd62a0998;hb=1b2fefb244d7d2fd949104e743ff15d01bbe5bb0) but its contents are even less obvious.

One can imagine it's to cope with embedded environments and limited size: if the kernel patch allows to avoid shipping the conntrack tools, space is spared for other features.

It's a hack. The intended modern interactions with the *conntrack* subsystem is through the [`conntrack`](https://manpages.debian.org/conntrack/conntrack.8) tool and the [netlink](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages/netlink.7) kernel API, which is continually evolving. (Read-only) `/proc/net/nf_conntrack` is only kept around for compatibility with simpler tools.

You could probably compile a Debian source tree with this additional patch (possibly requiring other related patches) to get this feature, but I'm not sure that would really be useful on a normal system.